# Splitting plane for negative power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-voltage

I used op-amp for my project and supplied with +12 and -12 volts. My PCB will have 4 layers which are TOP (signal layer), POWER (internal plane), GROUND (internal plane), BOTTOM (signal layer). When I split the power plane for supply voltages such as +12V, +5V , +3.3V . I'm confused where to set my -12V power for op-amp supply.

Should I set -12V to POWER plane or GROUND plane and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the vast majority of applications -12V is a power net, while GND is, well, GND.

For a design with many different power rails it's better practice to just run power traces on the power layer, rather than trying to split it up into different pours.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I also found that [e-book](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=z-tRRE9O8xMC&pg=PA328&lpg=PA328&dq=splitting+ground+plane+for+negative+power+PCB&source=bl&ots=fEtzykHNCq&sig=ACfU3U3gQbSH9SydHktb-qx0-A2_SC4ueg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd-fWf35PkAhXyoIsKHeTKDxIQ6AEwFXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=splitting%20ground%20plane%20for%20negative%20power%20PCB&f=false) which has the same suggestion.

[image]